# Save multiple figures in one pdf page, matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I'm trying to get my figures in just one pdf page, but I don't know how to do this. I found out that it's possible to save multiple figures in a pdf file with 'matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf', but it doesn't work for just one page.
Has anyone any ideas ? Convert the figures to just one figure ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use matplotlib gridspec to have multiple plots in 1 window

http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import random
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(12, 16))
G = GridSpec(2,2)   
axes_1 = pl.subplot(G[0, :])

x = [random.gauss(3,1) for _ in range(400)]
bins = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
axes_1.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.5, label='x')

axes_2 = pl.subplot(G[1, :])
axes_2.plot(x)

pl.tight_layout()
pl.show()
```

You can change the rows and column values and can subdivide the sections.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF backend makes one page per figure. Use subplots to get multiple plots into one figure and they'll all show up together on one page of the PDF.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution provided by matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with PdfPages('foo.pdf') as pdf:
    #As many times as you like, create a figure fig and save it:
    fig = plt.figure()
    pdf.savefig(fig)

    ....
    fig = plt.figure()
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Voilà

Find a full example here: [multipage pdf matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html)

And by the way, for one figure, you don't need `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf` just add pdf extension like so:

```
plt.savefig("foo.pdf")
```

Comment: thx for this comment, but your code doesnt save all figures on one page, ist saves them on more pages.

Comment: You just need to use it properly, it saves all figures in one document: see the example on the link I gave you: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html

Comment: I see what you mean, then what you need are subplots, see demo: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html Then save to pdf.